# Passing Methods in Java

Tags: java, generics, method-reference

I'm trying to accomplish passing a method in Java.

Here is the birds-eye-view of what I'm trying to do as a dummy example:

```
public final class A {
  private String value;

  public A(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public final Object bind(Function<String, String> func) {
    this.value = func.apply(value);

    return this;
  }

  // Rest of the logic here to deal with `value`
}

public final class B {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A<T> a = new A("hello");
    a.bind(B::methodOne).bind(B::methodTwo);
  }

  private String methodOne(String s) {
    // method logic here

    return "haha";
  }

  private String methodTwo(String s) {
    // method logic here

    return "hi";
  }
}
```

So, basically, I've methods in a class, B in the above example, and I want to pass the methods of B to A and store the return value of that method of B on A for further processing.

I've tried to make use of `method reference` feature of Java but since I don't code daily with Java, I'm having a hard time getting my head around how to properly accomplish this while fulfilling the constraints above.

Currently, I'm getting a `incompatible types: invalid method reference` error while I do the binding in the main method.

### Update

Made changes on my constraints of the program.

Comment: I think this might not work. `methodThree` takes two arguments, so the appropriate type would be a `BiFunction` which is not compatible with a `Function`. Also, you're binding `T` to input and output of `Function`, which doesn't work for `methodOne`. You'd either need some kind of "multi"-function with variadic type parameters (which doesn't exist in Java), or maybe it could work with a `Function<ParameterContainer, T>`, where `ParameterContainer` is a type that you can define that contains a list of parameters for the function.

Comment: Generics won't work with primitives so you'd need to use overloaded `bind()` methods - but you'll probably need those anyway (one for no arguments, which basically takes a supplier, one for one argument and one for multiple arguments of the same type). However, how should binding those methods work? Could you explain that based on your code example? What should the result of each `bind()` step be and what would the input be?

Comment: Also note that `Function<T,T>` would try to infer the parameter and return type to the same basic type - in the case of `Integer methodOne(String s)` this would mean `T` would be inferred to `Object`. Also `A<T>` would already define `T` when the instance is created so assuming the constructor is something like `A(T value)` then `new A("hello").bind(method)` would require `method` to take and return a `String`.

Comment: @Thomas do see the updates please. I knew I was pushing it too hard. I've lowered my constraints.

Comment: @QBrute do see the updates please. I knew I was pushing it too hard. I've lowered my constraints.

Comment: After your edit, the situation changed quite a bit. Now, you're returning `Object` from  `bind`, even though you're using it for method chaining. Does the problem still persist, if you change the return type to `A` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing the expression `B::methodOne` in a static context.

non-static methods have an invisible parameter, called 'the receiver': It's the instance.

So, in a static context, `B::methodOne` has the signature: `(B, String) -> String`. What your bind method wants is `(String) -> String`, and these two are not compatible. Therefore, this does not work.

There are two ways to fix it:

1. create an instance: `B b = new B(); a.bind(b::methodOne);`. The expression `b::methodOne`, where b is a variable of type `B` referencing an actual instance of B (as created with `new B()`) DOES have the signature `(String) -> String` as required.
2. Make the `methodOne` method `static`, at which point it no longer has the invisible `B instance` parameter.

Your code is also littered with rookie mistakes; you must call `a.bind` and not `A.bind`, using A and B as class names is extremely confusing, your bind method returns Object (it should return `A`), etc. The way to fix those is to learn basic java, I think; trying to tackle those mistakes bit by bit seems unsuitable for what stackoverflow is for. Thus, I leave those as an exercise for you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Those rookie mistakes you’ve mentioned are actually merely typos as I was in a hurry. I’ve been programming for long. It’s just that Java isn’t my day-to-day language. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: The asker updated their question a lot after reading this answer. Crucially, originally each method had a completely different signature (different param types and amounts, and different return types). I'm leaving this answer untouched, be aware it is no longer particularly relevant to the question as it currently stands.**

This doesn't work well because the methods you want to pass have completely different signatures (methodOne's is `(B, String) -> int` (why do you have a capital I `Int` in there, is that a typo?), methodTwo is `(B) -> String`, and methodThree is `(B, String, String) -> String`.

In java lambdas must fit a functional interface. It is not possible to have a functional interface for a variable number of input arguments.

With generics you can attempt to paper over the fact that the types of your inputs and output are different every time.

This really sounds like an X/Y problem: You have problem X (which you didn't explain and we don't know what it is), and you thought: I know! I'll use lambdas to abstract away the notion of 'a method'... and now you're asking questions about that.

But you're asking the wrong question. Ask X. Because even if hypothetically you could somehow fit your 3 methods all in the same lambda type (you can't), you would not then be able to invoke them.

Here's one more workable notion, but I have no idea if it solves your X because you didn't explain this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyXThinger {
    Object result(Object... args);
}
```

If you want to invoke this, how would you know that the particular `MyXThinger` (you didn't explain what X is, so I can't come up with a good name here) works if you pass 2 strings, and crashes if you pass anything else? That's.. more or less why I find your problem description insufficient to give solid advice here.

Comment: Yeah, the `Int` was a typo. Actually, this is exaclty what I'm trying to achieve. I know it looks abstract but I'm working on something abstract and experimental. That's why it could be confusing. However, I made changes to my constraints. I had a feeling I was pushing too hard. Please see the edit.